# OpenXML Remove text from template

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml, openxml-sdk

I have a number of .docx templates that customers download, but certain words need to be changed or removed from the document for different customers. I can't find anything on how to remove text:-

```
using (WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(memoryStream, true))
{
  foreach (Text element in doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Descendants<Text>())
  {
   //This is fine
   element.Text = element.Text.Replace("DocumentDate", wordReferenceTemplatesMV.DocumentDate)

   //Need help on how to remove text 
   element.Text = element.Text.Remove???("TextToRemove")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just replace it with an empty string?

```
element.Text = element.Text.Replace("TextToRemove", string.Empty);
```

Comment: Would be an option but it’s for the 3rd line of an address, which some customers don’t have. By putting an empty string it just creates an empty line in the address section in the word document whick looks bad.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the element any more then you can delete the whole element:

```
using (WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(memoryStream, true))
{
    foreach (Text element in doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Descendants<Text>())
    {
        if (element.Text == "TextToRemove")
            element.Remove();
    }
}
```

**Edit**

If you're left with an empty line the chances are you have a `Paragraph` that contained the `Text`. In that case you want to remove the `Paragraph` instead in which case you can do:

```
if (element.Text == "TextToRemove")
    element.Parent.Remove();
```

Comment: thanks this worked as well - took the text out, but still left me with an empty line. See above comment

Comment: @user2052656 - I've updated the answer to cover that scenario. Let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Most text values are in Run element. Basically you can run through all the Run elements and check its text. it should be something like:

```
Body body = wordprocessingDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;
foreach (Run r in body.Descendants<Run>())
{
    string sText = r.InnerText ;
    //...compare the text with the value
    //note sometime, you could see the text be broken into two runs, you need to find a way based on your requirements and connect them.    }
```

if you want to delete the text, you can just delete the run.
call the run's remove() method.

```
r.Remove();
```

[More details about Runs and text object,](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/working-with-runs)

If you use the file as template, usually I will set some special properties on the Run element, so later, I can find them with more accuracy.
for example, inside the run loop, before checking its text, you can check the color first.

```
if( r.RunProperties.Highlight.Val == DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.HighlightColorValues.Yellow )
{
    string sText = r.InnerText ;
    ....
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Helped a lot thanks, it's deleting the text ok but unfortunately I'm still left with an empty line. I think the best thing I can do is remove the field from the template completely 'Address2', then if its required add it to the previous line 'Address1' with a Break() in the middle.. . How would I add a Break() in between 2 fields and then add them to the document:- Address1 +  Break() + Address2

Comment: I think the break you mentioned is the paragraph object which is the parent object of Run. if you want to remove the whole paragraph, you can call r.Parent.Remove(); also, you can new a paragraph, insert a Run with text into it. Usually I will insert a new Paragrath after r.Parent, then call r.Parent.Remove(). something like that to update text content.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's the paragraph element causing the empty line when removed.

Clients send over a template with an address block as:-

[address1]

[address2]

[city]

[town]

[state]

[zip]

The fields are populated from the database with the replace function, but if an address doesn't contain an [address2] value, that's what I need removing. If I remove the text, I'm still left with an empty line between [address1] and [city]. The [address2] field isn't in it's own paragraph.